# Socket.IO 1.0.4 Websocket Server

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I want to create a websocket server with NodeJS and Socket.IO but it wont work.
I tried several scripts which people used in their tutorials but always when i connect i get error: undefined.
~MrJoki007

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
var server = require( 'http' ).createServer( app );
server.listen( 3009 ); //port for your socket...
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var io = socket.listen( server );
```

make sure you install [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io)

Comment: Sry for the late answere!
It says app is not defined. What is app?